# webfilter css missing when redirecting requests

Tags: jsf, servlet-filters, servlet-3.0

i am working on webfilter to control access to all pages in my JSF application,the filter makes sure if the user is logged in then redirect him to his home page  ,if not the user will be redirected to the login form , every thing works fine but the pages doesn't look good (no css)

this is my web filter

`@WebFilter(filterName = "UsersessionFilter",

    urlPatterns = {"/*"})

    public class UsersessionFilter implements Filter {`

the redirection part in my webfilter

```
      if (useression != null) {  
            boolean islogged = useression.getEmployee() != null;  
            if (!islogged) {  
                if (!_curent_Request_url.equals(_context_path + "/faces/wolcome.xhtml")) {  
                    httpresponse.sendRedirect(_context_path + "/faces/wolcome.xhtml");  
                } else {  
                    chain.doFilter(request, response);  
                }  

            } else  {  
                try {  
                    employee = useression.getEmployee() ;  
                } catch (Exception ex) {  
                    Logger.getLogger(UsersessionFilter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);  
                }  
                if (("E").equals(employee.getGrad()) && !_curent_Request_url.equals(_context_path + "/faces/mainEmployee.xhtml")) {  
                    httpresponse.sendRedirect(_context_path + "/faces/mainEmployee.xhtml");  
                } else if (("R").equals(employee.getGrad()) && !_curent_Request_url.equals(_context_path + "/faces/mainAdmin.xhtml")) {  
                    httpresponse.sendRedirect(_context_path + "/faces/mainAdmin.xhtml");  
                }  
                else  
                    chain.doFilter(request, response);  
            }  
        }  
        else chain.doFilter(request, response);
```

i am using glassfish server 3.1.2

thank's

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14467153/870122

Comment: yes,i tried but still no result ,thank's